# Copying a char** into another char** (C)

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a

```
char **content;
```

that contains lines of text, and in order to change some lines I create a

```
char **temp;
```

and copy (with `strncpy`) whatever I need from `content` to `temp`.
so when it's ok I have a `char **content` that has the old content, and a `char **temp` that has the new content and I want to replace my `char **content` by `temp`.

I tried a naive `content=temp;` without results of course...

I tried to free each element of my `char **content` and then `content=temp;` but nothing changed, and I can't free content itself.

I tried

```
void swappointers(char ***content,char ***temp){
    char **t = *content;
    *content = *temp;
    *temp = t;
}
swappointers(&content,&temp);
```

without success.

How to swap them?

EDIT:
Minimal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINES 7
#define MAXLENGTH 255


void print(char **content){
    int countline=0;
    while(content[countline]!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",content[countline]);  
        countline++;
    }
}

void swappointers(char ***content,char ***tempcontent){
    char **temp = *content;
    *content = *tempcontent;
    *tempcontent = temp;
}

void addline(char **content,char *texttoadd,int linetoinsert){
    char **tempcontent=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAXLINES);

    int countline=0;
    int contentline=0;
    while(content[contentline]!=NULL){
        if(countline==linetoinsert){
            //add our text
            tempcontent[countline] = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
            strncpy(tempcontent[countline],texttoadd,MAXLENGTH);

            //add \0 (string end character)
            int linelength=strlen(tempcontent[countline])-1;
            for (int countchar=linelength;countchar>=0;countchar--){
                if(tempcontent[countline][countchar]=='\r'||tempcontent[countline][countchar]=='\n'){
                    //end line char
                    tempcontent[countline][countchar+1]='\0';
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            //copy from content
            tempcontent[countline]=content[contentline];
            contentline++;
        }
        countline++;
    }
    tempcontent[countline]=NULL;
    printf("tempcontent:\n");
    print(tempcontent);
    swappointers(&content,&tempcontent);
}

int main(){
    //allocate memory for our future content
    char **content = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAXLINES);

    content[0] = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
    strncpy(content[0],"line 0",MAXLENGTH);
    content[1] = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
    strncpy(content[1],"line 2",MAXLENGTH);
    content[2] = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
    strncpy(content[2],"line 3",MAXLENGTH);
    content[3] = NULL;

    printf("________FILE BEFORE________\n");
    print(content);

    addline(content,"line 1",1);

    printf("________FILE AFTER________\n");
    print(content);
}
```

Output:

```
________FILE BEFORE________
line 0
line 2
line 3
tempcontent:
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
________FILE AFTER________
line 0
line 2
line 3
```

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].  BTW: usually if you need to have `***` there is something wrong with your approach.

Comment: added code and the output I have

Comment: You have another problem in your code: `print` prints the lines until it encounters a `NULL` pointer, but you don't add a `NULL` pointer into the array neither in `main` nor in `addline`. So your code happens to work more or less, because apparently on your platform `malloc` fills the allocated memory with zeros. On my computers I get a crash.

Comment: if my content has 4 lines  and content malloc'd for let's say 10 lines, content[3] is the last line and content[4] is NULL, isn't it ?
(using -Wall -g)

Comment: No, it is uninizialized. As I write before `malloc` doesn't initialize the allocated memory. Maybe it's `NULL` on _your_ platform (which by the ways is what?).

Comment: Read the first lines of the [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) manpage.

Comment: Linux mint 18 (~Xenial 16.04)
So how to loop and end where there is nothing anymore..? Should I fill content with NULL pointers when initializing it ?

Comment: Just put a `NULL` pointer after the last valid element. In `main` you would need to put `content[3] = NULL;` right after `strncpy(content[2], "line 3", MAXLENGTH);`. In `addlines` it's similar.

Comment: Thanks, I should pay more attention to that.
I edited, but still don't have the results :(

Answer (score 1):

If `char **content` has "lines of text" then `content` points to an array where each element has a pointer to a string (line of text).

Suppose you have 10 lines. Then you allocate `content` as:

```
content= malloc(10*sizeof(char *));
```

Suppose each line has no more than 80 characters, then you allocate the first line as:

```
content[0]= malloc(80+1);  //add one for the terminating \0
strcpy(content[0], myline);
```

Now, from this example, you can figure out how to allocate the other lines, allocate `temp`, copy lines to `temp` and do whatever you need to do.

When you are done, don't forget to release the memory:

```
free(content[0]); //...and free the other lines as well
free(content);
```

---

EDIT:

You added code and asked me to look at it. I have the following comments:

1. After `strncpy` ALWAYS place a null character in the last position! `strncpy` doesn't do that for you and any memory allocated with `malloc` is not zero initialized:

   ```
   strncpy(content[0],"line 0",MAXLENGTH);
   content[0][MAXLENGTH-1]= '\0';
   ```
2. For `addline` to work, i.e. swapping the pointers, you must pass it the address of `content` in `main` and swap must be then be called in `addline` as follows:

   ```
   addline(char ***content, etc);       // prototype
   swappointers(content,&tempcontent);  // call in addline
   addline(&content,"line 1",1);        // call in main
   ```
3. After `swappointers` you must free `tempcontent`

Comment: I use malloc(line_length) and not line_length+1 but I still set the last char to \0, what do you think about the code I added ?

Comment: had problems with that...
I finaly get what I want by making addline return a char** and in main : content=addline(); but not sure how memory is managed here

Comment: Vertus, it is important that you learn (investigate) how the memory is managed. It is the basis of your code. Taking the code into a debugger and stepping through it can help.